# JavaScript section scroll event

Tags: javascript

I have a sticky menu in my single page website. I want to create a JavaScript scroll event for specific section. When I reach to the `<main></main>` section and scroll 60px from the `<main>`, then scroll event enable. How can I do that? How can I create JavaScript scroll event for specific section.

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<header class="home" id="home">
    Slider Banner
</header>

<main class="main-section">
    <section class="about" id="about">About</section>

    <section class="team" id="team">Team</section>

    <section class="service" id="service">Service</section>

    <section class="portfolio" id="portfolio">Portfolio</section>
</main>

<footer class="footer" id="contact">Contact</footer>
```

Comment: When you say "sticky" are you referring to `position: sticky;` in CSS?

Comment: I want to enable this "sticky" menu only, when I scroll 60px from the <main>

Comment: See [How To Create a Fixed Header on Scroll](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp) as this can all be done with css. However, the reason for 60px and the expect effect is unclear.